# display special character correctly

Tags: android, encoding

I have got the problem, that I can't display special characters like 'ß, ö, ä, ü' in my app.

The result is like this: 
[image]

Or like this:

[image]

In `Android Studio` I get no error or warning and I am using the `windows-1251` encoding.

In gradle I added this line: `compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'`

It shall be german encoding.

How to fix that?

I actually can change special characters like 'ß' from predefined Strings with `Html.fromHtml( unicode of the special character)` like `Html.fromHtml ( "&#223" )`

But what if a non predefined String contains a special Character? I have tried to simple replace the special character like this:

```
 String neuer_String =  get_street_adress.replace ( "ß", Html.fromHtml ( "&#223" ) ) ;
 straße.setText ( "Stra" + Html.fromHtml ( "&#223" ) + "e: " + neuer_String);
```

But this doesn't work, because the string FriedhofstraÃe for example should be Friedhofstraße. So there is no character 'ß' in the string.

I also tried to change the font with `Typeface` but a exception is thrown: "native typeface cannot be made"

Comment: One possible reason is the fonts in your android device might not support the characters.

Comment: Try using UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably 'cause of the font in your device.
The way you can resolve this is by coding a Typeface out of a working font that you have tested.(e.g in Word,etc)

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/theNameOfTheFont.ttf");
```

Remember to place the code in fonts folder in assets. If you don't have one, create it.

Using UTF-8 encoding "might" solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's strongly recommended to use UTF-8 encoding.

With UTF-8 encoding, you can easily use the unicode value in your string.xml.
Here the [a Link to XML character Entities List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

For example for ß use `<string name="text szlig">text &#223;</string>`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it with the UTF-8 encoding. Nothing changed. Because I haven't got much Strings in xml I had to do this programmatically.  So I used `Html.fromHtml( "&#223")` to show the letter 'ß' for example. But this only works for defined strings. How to replace all special characters from a non predefined string?

Comment: Where do you get these strings ? from a server or the entry of the user ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the settings of Android Studio. In the File Encoding tab, make everything be formatted as UTF-8.

If the problem still persists, then the problem is in the font you are using as it may not support special characters.

I have found a solution for your problem, check it:

You can save all your strings with special characters in your strings.xml like:

```
<resources>

    <string name="street">Straße</string>

</resources>
```

Then retrieve them in code like:

```
String street = getResources().getString(R.string.street);
```

You can definitely try other german characters out. Hope that works for you!